# How to embed sliced PSD image with hyperlinks into Drupal CMS?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, html, image-format

Is it possible to slice an image in Photoshop, add hyperlinks to certain image areas and embed it into a Drupal CMS page?

I am new to this, but looks like it's possible to add a source of HTML code in the CMS.
Is it sufficient to export images in html from Photoshop, or should the DreamWeaver be involved for this?
Also, the sliced image should be stored on the server?

Appreciate any thoughts/inputs.

Comment: It's hard to give advice on what to do since we do not know what you're going to be doing in Drupal. Are you creating a website from scratch in Drupal or using a template? It seems like you need a deeper understanding of HTML, CSS, and Drupal in general.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to slice an image in Photoshop, add hyperlinks to
> certain image areas and embed it into a Drupal CMS page?

Yes, after you have made your slices using the Slice Tool (C), use the Slice Selection Tool (C) and double-click on the slice. A dialogue box of options will open. You can add the Hyperlink to the URL spot.

> I am new to this, but looks like it's possible to add a source of HTML
> code in the CMS.

You can use File -> Export -> Save for Web (Legacy). Then save. Under format, choose HTML and images. This will create a HTML file with your images. I would NOT recommend using this process to create a website or web pages.

> Is it sufficient to export images in html from Photoshop, or should
> the DreamWeaver be involved for this?

I would use Photoshop to create images and a text editor (or Dreamweaver) to write the code for the website.

> Also, the sliced image should be stored on the server?

Yes

Comment: Thank you so much for such an accurate answer! Really helpful.
And now I understood why it's not recommended to use HTML from Photoshop for the web page. In Dreamweaver all looks good, but on CMS there is odd spacing between the image slices (Any ideas how to fix this?)
Also, I know responsiveness should be taken care of.

Comment: @Olenia It's hard to say why there is spacing when using the code from Photoshop. Whatever template you're using in Drupal is adding some type of margin or padding to your images. It is not recommended to build website using only images/slices. I would recommend building the website using HTML and CSS.